# Xamarin ZXing Qr to List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In my project i need contunistly read barcode and put them in a list. But while i trying it its always giving me NullReferenceException but i didn't get it. When i check it in debug i can see it have a string value but while trying put it to list its always giving me that error. Its my code for Scan and take data :

```
 List<HoldMyString> mylist;  
 HoldMyString hold;
    private void ZXingScannerView_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            hold.HoldString = result.Text;  // HoldString is taking string value

            mylist.Add(hold);    
           

            
        });
    }
```

How i  can put my datas in to my list contunistly. Thanks for help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi @Uğurcan Uçar, you declare `hold` with `HoldMyString` type but you didn't initialize it. Thus it is `null`. So when you try to access its properties, you will get `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the same error with yours.
[image]

You could use the code below.

HoldMyString:

```
 public class HoldMyString
{
    public string HoldString { get; set; }
}
```

Code for Scan and take data:

```
  List<HoldMyString> mylist=new List<HoldMyString>();
    HoldMyString hold = new HoldMyString();
    private void Handle_OnScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            hold.HoldString = result.Text;  // HoldString is taking string value

            mylist.Add(hold);
        });
    }
```

For more details about how to get the barcodes, you could check the thread i done before.
[How to embed ZXing scanner in PageRenderer/Fragment/View into Xamarin.Forms ContentPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705760/how-to-embed-zxing-scanner-in-pagerenderer-fragment-view-into-xamarin-forms-cont)