# Xamarin Forms, How to scan a barcode from another application and get a response?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am using zxing to scan barcodes, zxing is not working as well as I would like. Requires scanning with external QRbot app. I run QRbot from the app, but I don't know how to get the response, after scanning, the URL opens. How to get value? (Google translate).
QRbot Documentation https://ioshelp.qrbot.net/xcallback

```
private async void btn_zxing_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) // scan zxing
        {
            var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();
            await Navigation.PushAsync(scan);
            scan.OnScanResult += (result) =>
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();
                    searchInfo(result.ToString());
                });
            };
        }
```

Launching QRbot, I don't know how to get the Barcode.

```
private async void QRbot_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://qrbot.net/x-callback-url/scan?x-success=https%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com");
            await Browser.OpenAsync(uri, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ZXingScannerView` to scan the barcode without QRbot.

```
   <zxing:ZXingScannerView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="_scanView" OnScanResult="Handle_OnScanResult" IsScanning="true"
                        WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" />
```

For more details about the code sample, you could check the code sample i done before.
[How to embed ZXing scanner in PageRenderer/Fragment/View into Xamarin.Forms ContentPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59705760/how-to-embed-zxing-scanner-in-pagerenderer-fragment-view-into-xamarin-forms-cont/59712540#59712540)

Comment: This scanner view does not work any where near as well as the QRBot external app. I have a usecase where we have tried ZXing however it doesn't read smaller barcodes and we are required to use QRBot or use a paid solution